# Java issue, test it timing out, need to fix my method - choose

Tags: java

Hey the release tests on my project have this code timing out, because it ca only take the time proportional to the number of unique objects, how can i trim the time down?

Given a random number generator, randomly choose an element from the Bag
according to the distribution of objects in the Bag (e.g., if a Bag
contains 7 a's and 3 b's, then 70% of the time choose should return an a,
and 30% of the time it should return a b.

This operation can take time proportional to the number of unique objects
in the Bag, but no more.

This operation should not affect the Bag.
 @param r
            Random number generator
 @return randomly chosen element

```
public T choose(Random r) {
    ArrayList<T> keyArrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
    int index = 0;
    Iterator<T> it = denseBagMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
         T current = it.next();
         while (index < denseBagMap.get(current)){
             keyArrayList.add(current);
             index++;
         }
         index = 0;
    }
    return keyArrayList.get(r.nextInt(keyArrayList.size()));
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what is the problem again ?

Comment: is this a question? `if(Math.random() <= 0.7) return a else return b`.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could do `for (T current : denseBagMap.keySet())` instead of using an iterator, unless you don't support Java 7. It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a JUnit (even though it doesn't look like it, you might want to turn it into one), you may want to define a [timeout](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) for the test and make it less random. You can also use a [parametrized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) test which will help you run the test with different input values, though I believe the timeout will be the same for all the different set of parameters.